# Avoid white space in references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have used latex for preparation of my thesis. My references look like following. How to avoid white space in the references?[image]

Comment: not knowing how your bibliography input is coded, i suggest entering the url with the command `\url{http...}` and adding `\usepackage{url}` to your preamble.  this will allow the url to be broken at "reasonable" places, and still be linkable with `hyperref` (need to specify `breaklinks`; see the documentation for specifics).

Comment: @barbara beeton : Thank you very much for your comment. Problem was, that I haven't used "\url"

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to change the bibliography style. Note: other users might be more experienced with this and so another solution might be presented, but I used the method to induce a line break before printing the URL.